# Shotwell slideshow without the need of copying all photos

Tags: shotwell, slideshow

The program shotwell copies all photos to its own directory to create a slideshow. I have a folder with 10GB of pictures, and to make this 20GB just to make a slideshow is not a very solid idea. Is there a way to just select a folder and make Ubuntu slide through the pictures in that folder, without the need of duplicating pictures?

Yes, I could copy the pictures to the shotwell directory and only have them there, but I have them saved in my cloud, which I access through nautilus by using InSync.

Comment: I use the "import in place" option in Shotwell, so it only copies links, not the photos themselves.

Comment: Hmm, I have not seen that option, I will try that out, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, can you put it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shotwell has an option to "import in place" which only copies links, not the photos themselves.  Use of this option can prevent having to use storage space to actually copy the photos.

The option can be selected from this prompt **after** selecting a folder to import through *File => Import From Folder...*

[image: Screenshot of copy/import prompt]